# Why does @Url.Action cause a compile time error in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I can't use @Url.Action in ASP.NET Core because I have error:

> IUrlHelper has no applicable method named Action

I want to use @Url.Action for:

```
<a href="@(Url.Action(ViewBag.actionName, ViewBag.controllerName, new { page = i }) + ViewBag.routeValues)">page i</a>
```

In ASP.NET MVC it generated me urls for example:

> /Home/List?page=5&search=abc

In ViewBag.routeValues I pass additional parameters, for example: **search=abc&active=true** and paste it to url **after 'page' parameter**.

I think I can't do the same using tag helper and 'asp-route' - so what can I do?

---

**Ok - I need to cas ViewBag to string:**

```
<a href="@(Url.Action((string)ViewBag.actionName, (string)ViewBag.controllerName, new { page = i }) + (string)ViewBag.routeValues)">page i</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

You should first read the [ASP.NET Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms) to find out what tag helpers are and how to use them.

In ASP.NET Core's Razor implementation, tag helpers are used instead of helper methods.

```
<a href="@(Url.Action(ViewBag.actionName, ViewBag.controllerName, new { page = i }) + ViewBag.routeValues)">page i</a>
```

would translate into

```
<a asp-controller="@ViewBag.actionName" asp-action="@ViewBag.controllerName" asp-route-id = "@i">page i</a>
```

"asp-route" can be either a route parameter or a query parameter (if the given action has no such route parameter). so `asp-route-xyz="abc"` would add `?xyz=abc` to the url.

Comment: Then use `asp-all-route-data` tag helper, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229707/append-querystring-to-href-in-asp-net-core-anchor-helper-tag/43231971#43231971)