# Efficient way to bring parameters into controller action URL's

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.Net Core you have multiple ways to generate an URL for controller action, the newest being tag helpers.

Using tag-helpers for GET-requests `asp-route` is used to specify route parameters. It is from what I understand not supported to use complex objects in route request. And sometimes a page could have many different links pointing to itself, possible with minor addition to the URL for each link.

To me it seems wrong that any modification to controller action signature requires changing all tag-helpers using that action. I.e. if one adds `string query` to controller, one must add query to model and add `asp-route-query="@Model.Query"` 20 different places spread across cshtml-files. Using this approach is setting the code up for future bugs.

Is there a more elegant way of handling this? For example some way of having a Request object? (I.e. request object from controller can be put into Model and fed back into action URL.)

Comment: [`asp-all-route-data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2#asp-all-route-data) might help with your specific problem here. I wouldn't be so dismissive of Chris's advice (it's solid), but I get that sometimes the changes required to "do things properly" isn't so practical.

Comment: Thank you, I've looked into route-data as one option. But it would require either parameters read as `Dictionary<string, string>` (value is string type) in action, or objects reflected into `Dictionary<string, string>`. That would be my fallback, but was hoping maybe there was an even better option.

Comment: Did you mean something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231971/455493)? Not that I would recommend such an query-pass-through approach

Comment: Thanks. The solution proposed there seems like it would work. The problem described has been solved in ASP.Net Core now, `asp-route-*` is applied after `asp-all-route-data`. So the solution would probably work without the extended Dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

In my other answer I found a way to provide request object through Model.

From the SO article @tseng provided I found a smaller solution. This one does not use a request object in Model, but retains all route parameters unless explicitly overridden. It won't allow you to specify route through an request object, which is most often not what you want anyway. But it solved problem in OP.

`<a asp-controller="Test" asp-action="HelloWorld" asp-all-route-data="@Context.GetQueryParameters()" asp-route-somestring="optional override">Link</a>`

This requires an extension method to convert query parameters into a dictionary.

`public static Dictionary GetQueryParameters(this HttpContext context)
{
    return context.Request.Query.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value.ToString());
}`

Comment: Shortly `asp-all-route-data="@Context.Request.Query.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value.ToString())"`

Answer (score 0):

There's a rationale here that I don't think you're getting. GET requests are intentionally simplistic. They are supposed to describe a specific resource. They do no have bodies, because you're not supposed to be passing complex data objects in the first place. That's not how the HTTP protocol is designed.

Additionally, query string params should generally be optional. If some bit of data is required in order to identify the resource, it should be part of the main URI (i.e. the path). As such, neglecting to add something like a `query` param, should simply result in the full data set being returned instead of some subset defined by the `query`. Or in the case of something like a search page, it generally will result in a form being presented to the user to collect the `query`. In other words, you action should account for that param being missing and handle that situation accordingly.

Long and short, no, there is no way "elegant" way to handle this, I suppose, but the reason for that is that there doesn't need to be. If you're designing your routes and actions correctly, it's generally not an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your answer that you don't think I understand HTTP, that my use case is wrong and that I should design everything differently is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, the very act of having a "query" that is being passed all over the place is indicative of bad design. HTTP is stateless for a reason.

Comment: I believe you missed the point, pattern - not specific use case. "Query" was an example parameter. In my use case today it is the customer id and section. Every link to the page will have to carry these as I want to avoid using cookies to store where user is currently navigated. I also want to avoid encapsulating every link in a form for postback. A lack of "customer id" cannot return all customers, that would require a listing page. That would require me to combine two separate views into one controller. Seems like a lot extra code for nothing.

Comment: Why is using the parameter "query" indicative of bad design by the way?

Comment: Passing *anything* all over the place is bad design, not just "query". If every link has to have some *thing* attached to it, that's a bad design. Something like a "customer id" should be either associated with authentication, where it can then be a claim or something, or it should go into the session, if you truly need to persist throughout the client's requests. You do not need to set an explicit cookie, but cookies are required for persisting state, that's the entire point of their existence.

Comment: What's you're trying to achieve here is basically the same as "cookie-less sessions", which are an artifact of the past for a reason. They don't work, and cause all sorts of issues. Cookies are not a bad thing. If you need to be GDPR compliant, you need only inform your users that you're using them, and allow them to opt out. However, it's perfectly okay if opting out means that your site effectively cannot be used. It's simply not tenable to avoid cookies entirely unless you have an extremely basic, virtually static website.

Comment: Well, all I wanted was to pass the customerid into the URL when admin edits a certain customer. This escalated quickly. I think we're GDPR compliant.

Comment: @TeddHansen: Why get query then? an MVC-esque url would be `/admin/customer/{customerId}/Edit` (get request to display the edit form, post request to persist the changes) or in WebApi `/api/admin/customer/{customerId}` GET to read, PUT to create/replace the resources data, post/patch to modify it. Like most frameworks, ASP.NET Core is opinionated (biased) to the MVC/REST Api patterns and such general pass-through of query parameters aren't really part of that pattern

Comment: The page could contain more than just edit-form for customer, for example list of items on left side of page for quick navigation. We'd need customer id, filter for a left menu (search result) and possibly information about view. `/customer/{customerid}/{view}?query=Oslo`. If we decide to expand filter to `?query=Oslo&category=A` we would have to update 20+ a href links in cshtml-pages with `asp-route-category="@Model.Route.Category"`. Missing one link would result in "category" being lost when user clicks link. My goal was to remove this dependency in the code itself. Not about MVC per se.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I'd like to have a request object used as route parameters for anchor TagHelper. This means that all route links are defined in only one location, not throughout solution. Changes made to request object model automatically propagates to URL for `<a asp-action>`-tags.

The benefit of this is reducing number of places in the code we need to change when changing method signature for a controller action. We localize change to model and action only.

I thought writing a tag-helper for a custom `asp-object-route` could help. I looked into chaining Taghelpers so mine could run before `AnchorTagHelper`, but that does not work. Creating instance and nesting them requires me to hardcode all properties of [ASP.Net Cores AnchorTagHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/AnchorTagHelper.cs), which may require maintenance in the future. Also considered using a custom method with UrlHelper to build URL, but then TagHelper would not work.

The solution I landed on is to use `asp-all-route-data` as suggested by @kirk-larkin along with an extension method for serializing to Dictionary. Any `asp-all-route-*` will override values in `asp-all-route-data`.

`<a asp-controller="Test" asp-action="HelloWorld" asp-all-route-data="@Model.RouteParameters.ToDictionary()" asp-route-somestring="optional override">Link</a>`

ASP.Net Core can deserialize complex objects (including lists and child objects).
`public IActionResult HelloWorld(HelloWorldRequest request) { }`

In the request object (when used) would typically have only a few simple properties. But I thought it would be nice if it supported child objects as well. Serializing object into a Dictionary is usually done using reflection, which can be slow. I figured Newtonsoft.Json would be more optimized than writing simple reflection code myself, and found this implementation ready to go:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

    public static IDictionary ToDictionary(this object metaToken)
    {
        // From https://geeklearning.io/serialize-an-object-to-an-url-encoded-string-in-csharp/
        if (metaToken == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        JToken token = metaToken as JToken;
        if (token == null)
        {
            return ToDictionary(JObject.FromObject(metaToken));
        }

        if (token.HasValues)
        {
            var contentData = new Dictionary();
            foreach (var child in token.Children().ToList())
            {
                var childContent = child.ToDictionary();
                if (childContent != null)
                {
                    contentData = contentData.Concat(childContent)
                        .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
                }
            }

            return contentData;
        }

        var jValue = token as JValue;
        if (jValue?.Value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var value = jValue?.Type == JTokenType.Date ?
            jValue?.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) :
            jValue?.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return new Dictionary { { token.Path, value } };
    }
}
```