# Overwrite RouteValues from asp-all-route-data in AnchorTagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When using TagHelpers with MVC Core (2.1) it is possible to define `asp-all-route-data` and additional `asp-route-x`. But if x is alreay contained inside the object passed to all-route-data, an exception is thrown:

```
An element with the key 'x' already exists in the RouteValueDictionary
```

Is it possible to change this behavior (extend TagHelper, custom TagHelper, etc) to just update the value in this case instead of trying to create a new entry.

So this:

```
if(RouteValueDictionary.HasKey(x)) 
   RouteValueDictionary[x] = value;
```

instead of (probably something like) this:

```
RouteValueDictionary.Add(x, value);
```

(Basically the if in my code isn't even necessary in an assignment like this)

Edit (maybe to explain the use case): There is an object with all the query parameters for a form, but there are also links  that should basically send the same data and change a value. Submitting the form would only work if using javascript with an onclick for every link, setting the hidden input and submitting the form. But I would prefer not using JS for this as features like "middle click to new tab" will be lost.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231971/455493) helps?

Comment: @Tseng this actually looks good. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Answer from Tseng is very useful, however if it's necessary to use an Object for the Values and not the context it might not work that well.

In the end we created a TagHelper that only creates the query parameters:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteValuesDictionaryName)]
[HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteValuesPrefix + "*")]
public class SearchLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string RouteValuesDictionaryName = "my-all-route-data";
    private const string RouteValuesPrefix = "my-route-";
    private const string Href = "href";

    private IDictionary<string, string> _routeValues;

    public override int Order => 1;

    [HtmlAttributeName(RouteValuesDictionaryName, DictionaryAttributePrefix = RouteValuesPrefix)]
    public IDictionary<string, string> RouteValues
    {
        get => _routeValues ?? (_routeValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        set => _routeValues = value;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Attributes.TryGetAttribute(Href, out var href);

        var fixedRouteValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var (newKey, value) in _routeValues.Where(r=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Value)))
        {
            var key = fixedRouteValues.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => string.Equals(k, newKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) ?? newKey;
            fixedRouteValues[key] = value;
        }

        var query = string.Join("&", fixedRouteValues.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value}"));
        var hrefValue = href.Value;
        output.Attributes.Remove(href);
        href = new TagHelperAttribute(Href, hrefValue + "?" +query);
        output.Attributes.Add(href);

    }
}
```