# Razor Pages Return to same page but keep same URL (query string) (.Net Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a page that that inserts and edits products.

When I want to create a new product I go to "/Management/Products"
If the user is creating a new product and a error occurs or some field had bad data I send a message to the user and simply do:

```
await LoadDataAsync(); // loads data for some selects in the page

return Page(); // returns this page
```

But if I want to edit a Product I go to "/Management/Products?ProID=12"
And if the same happens and I need reload the page just as it was, but the above code "return Page()" redirects me to "/Management/Products" but I need to go back to 
"/Management/Products?ProID=12" so the page loads the correct product and the user can continuing editing it.

Is there a method that I'm not finding to reload the same page with the original url or a way of reloading the same page but with a query string?

Comment: First, it's bad design to  use query parameters for ids, better have it part of the routing, i.e. `/Management/Products/1` rather than `/Management/Products?id=1`, second you can set query parameters via `asp-route-xxx` where xxx is route parameter. Depending on the route, it will be part of path or query (if there is no xxx placeholder in the route). Third: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231971/455493) may be for you as it allows you to pass all parameters into a link via `asp-all-route-data="@Context.GetQueryParameters()"`

Comment: Tank you so much, I changed the url to be `/Management/Products/1` on update and that solved my problem.
I added `options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Management/Products", "Management/Products/{Id}");` on Startup and when I do the `return Page();` it reloads the Page correctly.
Once Again Thank You. :)

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. `Page()` doesn't redirect. Your problem is either the action of the form, or missing arguments to `RedirectToPage()`